# MariaDB SELECT query with date_add()

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have this particular salect query which acts strange:

(1)

```
select date_add(
        CURRENT_DATE(), 
        INTERVAL 7*0+(CASE 
                        WHEN tutoring_disponibilities.day < weekday(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                        THEN 7+(tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE()))
                        ELSE tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE())
                        END
                    ) 
        DAY
    ) from tutoring_disponibilities where date_add(
        CURRENT_DATE(), 
        INTERVAL 7*0+(CASE 
                        WHEN tutoring_disponibilities.day < weekday(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                        THEN 7+(tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE()))
                        ELSE tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE())
                        END
                    ) 
        DAY
    ) NOT IN (SELECT date(tutoring_sessions.startDate) from tutoring_sessions);
```

This returns nothing, but this (which is the first part of the where):
(2)

```
select date_add(
        CURRENT_DATE(), 
        INTERVAL 7*0+(CASE 
                        WHEN tutoring_disponibilities.day < weekday(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                        THEN 7+(tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE()))
                        ELSE tutoring_disponibilities.day-weekday(CURRENT_DATE())
                        END
                    ) 
        DAY
    ) 
    from tutoring_disponibilities;
```

returns:

```
'2020-03-30'
'2020-03-30'
'2020-03-31'
'2020-03-31'
'2020-03-25'
'2020-03-25'
```

and this part:
(3)

```
SELECT date(tutoring_sessions.startDate) from tutoring_sessions;
```

returns this:

```
'2020-01-29'
NULL
NULL
NULL
'2020-02-05'
'2020-02-05'
'2020-02-10'
'2020-02-11'
'2020-02-18'
'2020-02-17'
'2020-02-25'
'2020-02-24'
'2020-03-02'
'2020-03-09'
'2020-03-16'
'2020-03-23'
'2020-02-13'
'2020-02-13'
'2020-02-13'
'2020-02-24'
'2020-02-29'
'2020-03-14'
'2020-03-30'
'2020-03-30'
'2020-03-30'
```

We can see that `'2020-03-30'`is in the results of query (3) and also in the results of query (2), but the other results of query (2) are not present in the results of query (3).
So why query(1) doesn't return anything?
If you know a better way to express this code I would be glad of any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is not to use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  The reason is that *any* `NULL` value in the subquery causes no rows to be returned.

I recommend `NOT EXISTS`.  However, your expression is rather complicated, so the simplest fix to your query is:

```
NOT IN (SELECT date(tutoring_sessions.startDate)
        FROM tutoring_sessions
        WHERE tutoring_sessions.startDate IS NOT NULL
       )
```

With an index on `tutoring_sessions(startDate)`, the equivalent `NOT EXISTS` may also be noticeably faster.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I didn't know that any null values would have caused no rows to be returned.
Do you know any way to better express my code?
The purpose of this code is to get the matching dates of the two tables, considering that in tutoring_sessions dates are stored as timestamps and in tutoring_disponibilities dates are just day(0-6) and hour, then it finds the closest disposability to the current date

Comment: @EmanueleSacco . . . You have a complicated expression, so you might as well stick with the `WHERE` version, unless you find performance to be an issue.